# Get all combinations of list elements not ignoring position in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I want to combine all elements of a list into sublists (not tuples) with a specified length.

The `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` generator does nearly what I want to achieve:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement([1,2],2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

There are only two things I dislike: It creates tuples instead of sublists (what I could change with a map), and it misses the element `(2,1)` in the example above.

Is there any builtin module in Python 2 that does what I want? If not, is there any simple way to at least get `combinations_with_replacements` (or any other module function) to generate the missing element in the provided example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product([1, 2], repeat=2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```